# Setting current TabBarController view as root for UINavigationcontroller

Tags: objective-c, navigationcontroller, tabbarcontroller

I've been searching around for a good way to implement the hierarchy below.

I've completed the implementation of the login and the `UITabBarController` for the other three views.

What i need now is for the selected tab to act as the `rootviewcontroller` in my soon to be implemented `UINavigationcontroller`, which is supposed to handle pushing and popping from and to the detailed views.

**Hierarchy summary:**

```
LoginView--
    TabBarController - Holds it's own view and the three views below. 
             OneView (If selected should be root for UINavigationcontroller)
               - DetailView (DetailView of OneView)
                    -DetailView (Details of detailview)
             AnotherView (If selected should be root for UINavigationcontroller)
                - DetailView (DetailView of AnotherView)
                    -DetailView (Details of detailview)
             AThirdView (If selected should be root for UINavigationcontroller)
                - DetailView (DetailView of AThirdView)
                    -DetailView (Details of detailview)
```

The three views, lon, schema and tidsaldo are all connected to the `UITabBarController` in the interface builder.

So, what i basically need help with, is some guidelines and/or tips on how to make either of those three tabs the root for my `UINavigationController`.

What i've tried among other things is to grab hold of the `App Delegate` and adding the subview of the current `rootviewcontroller` for the `UINavigationController`. But that makes me loose the tabbar somehow.

Any tips and/or pointers are highly appreciated.

PS. There might be typos.

[image: Hierarchy structure]

Comment: Please check out [this][1] post.


Or this [tutorial][2]


  [1]: http://www.cimgf.com/2009/06/25/uitabbarcontroller-with-uinavigationcontroller-using-interface-builder/
  [2]: http://jduff.github.com/2010/03/09/throwing-a-uinavigationcontroller-uitabbarcontroller-and-uisearchbar-together/

Comment: Thanks, i looked at those and found some very neat stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by adding `Navigationcontrollers` in the `Tabbarcontroller` instead of `Viewcontrollers`.